# how my cocoa application can track streaming-audio activity

Tags: cocoa, macos, streaming, itunes, monitor

I have to develop a application to log online streaming information like opened player(iTunes,Quicktime),running track, total running time of particular track.

Answer (score 0):

> … online streaming information like opened player(iTunes,Quicktime),running track, total running time of particular track.

You can ask iTunes and QuickTime Player for this information using AppleScript. Make sure they're already running first—otherwise, your app will launch them, and the user will not like your app launching iTunes and QuickTime Player every few seconds.

iTunes posts distributed notifications for track changes, which you can use to avoid polling it repeatedly with AppleScript commands. You can determine the names of the distributed notifications by having [Notification Watcher](http://tildesoft.com/Programs.html) running while you change tracks. When the notification comes in, that's when you should send iTunes the AppleScript commands to get more information.